# Building for vue2 and vue3 in monorepo: Version mismatch error from vue-template-compiler

Tags: vue.js, vite, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

Let's say I have two packages in a monorepo using pnpm. One for Vue@3 (`package-a`), one other for Vue@2 (`package-b`). For the record, they both depend on a third package called `core`.

You can find what it looks like below:

```
.
├── .npmrc
├── .nvmrc
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── package-a
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   │   ├── .bin
│   │   │   │   ├── tsc
│   │   │   │   ├── tsserver
│   │   │   │   ├── vite
│   │   │   │   └── vue-tsc
│   │   │   ├── @myscope
│   │   │   │   └── core -> ../../../core
│   │   │   ├── @vitejs
│   │   │   │   └── plugin-vue -> ../../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@vitejs+plugin-vue@2.3.3_vite@2.9.9+vue@3.2.36/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
│   │   │   ├── typescript -> ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/typescript@4.6.4/node_modules/typescript
│   │   │   ├── vite -> ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/vite@2.9.9/node_modules/vite
│   │   │   ├── vue -> ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/vue@3.2.36/node_modules/vue
│   │   │   └── vue-tsc -> ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/vue-tsc@0.34.16_typescript@4.6.4/node_modules/vue-tsc
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
│   │   ├── tsconfig.node.json
│   │   └── vite.config.ts
│   ├── package-b
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   │   ├── .bin
│   │   │   │   ├── tsc
│   │   │   │   ├── tsserver
│   │   │   │   ├── vite
│   │   │   │   └── vue-tsc
│   │   │   ├── @myscope
│   │   │   │   └── core -> ../../../core
│   │   │   ├── typescript -> ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/typescript@4.6.4/node_modules/typescript
│   │   │   ├── vite -> ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/vite@2.9.9/node_modules/vite
│   │   │   ├── vite-plugin-vue2 -> ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/vite-plugin-vue2@2.0.1_dj3dtukdyynhbiqf2xbv2ocyei/node_modules/vite-plugin-vue2
│   │   │   ├── vue -> ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/vue@2.6.14/node_modules/vue
│   │   │   ├── vue-template-compiler -> ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/vue-template-compiler@2.6.14/node_modules/vue-template-compiler
│   │   │   └── vue-tsc -> ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/vue-tsc@0.34.16_typescript@4.6.4/node_modules/vue-tsc
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
│   │   ├── tsconfig.node.json
│   │   └── vite.config.ts
│   └── core
│       ├── index.ts
│       └── package.json
├── pnpm-lock.yaml
└── pnpm-workspace.yaml
```

In `packages/package-a/package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "@myscope/package-a",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@myscope/core": "workspace:*",
    "vue": "^3.2.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "vite": "^2.9.9",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.34.7"
  }
}
```

In `packages/package-b/package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "@myscope/package-b",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@myscope/core": "workspace:*",
    "vue": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "vite": "^2.9.9",
    "vite-plugin-vue2": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.34.7"
  }
}
```

When I run `pnpm run build` in `package-b` (Vue@2) I get the version mismatch error whereas it shouldnt:

```
> vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build

failed to load config from /path/to/my/project/monorepo/packages/package-b/vite.config.ts
error during build:
Error: 

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@3.2.36 (/path/to/my/project/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/vue@3.2.36/node_modules/vue/index.js)
- vue-template-compiler@2.6.14 (/path/to/my/project/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/vue-template-compiler@2.6.14/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/package.json)

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.

    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/my/project/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/vue-template-compiler@2.6.14/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/index.js:10:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/my/project/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/vite-plugin-vue2@2.0.1_dj3dtukdyynhbiqf2xbv2ocyei/node_modules/vite-plugin-vue2/dist/utils/descriptorCache.js:34:42)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/my/project/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/vite-plugin-vue2@2.0.1_dj3dtukdyynhbiqf2xbv2ocyei/node_modules/vite-plugin-vue2/dist/main.js:35:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

It seems that the resolved version doesn't follows `package.json` and uses `Vue@3` instead of `Vue@2`. I don't understand why. Could this be a bug about how `vue-template-compiler` resolves Vue or something?

A "dirty" workaround I've found to get it work is to add [`hoist=false` to `.npmrc`](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#hoist) at the project's root but I don't know what are the possible side-effects I can get by doing this. Anyway, is there a cleaner way to fix this?

PS. This can be related to https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/11828 but I'm asking here do do not reply in a closed issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question since [I got help](https://discord.com/channels/325477692906536972/709030686945968188/978330467482882048) on the VueJS discord server.

> There are two possible solutions that both worked for me independently:
>
> a) move vue-tsc to the root package.json. This is what I did as I try and keep all my project tooling out of the individual packages.
>
> b) use "pnpm.packageExtentions" in package.json to add vue@2 as a peer dependency of vue-template-compiler

Option a) doesn't seem to work as of pnpm@7 because of a [breaking change](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/blob/main/packages/pnpm/CHANGELOG.md#700):

> Dependencies of the root workspace project are not used to resolve peer dependencies of other workspace projects [#4469](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/pull/4469)

Option B with [`pnpm.packageExtensions`](https://pnpm.io/package_json#pnpmpackageextensions) is working fine. No need to add `nohoist=false` anymore to `.npmrc`.

```
diff --git i/package.json w/package.json
index 95cda08..182e89d 100644
--- i/package.json
+++ w/package.json
@@ -41,5 +41,14 @@
   "packageManager": "pnpm@7.1.3",
   "engines": {
     "node": ">=16.15.0"
+  },
+  "pnpm": {
+    "packageExtensions": {
+      "vue-template-compiler": {
+        "peerDependencies": {
+          "vue": "^2.6.14"
+        }
+      }
+    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: The biggest high five of the day to you, @bgondy! Really helped me out.

Comment: This should not be an issue as of `vue@2.7` since `vue-template-compiler` is not used anymore.